# Using a SQL SELECT * Insert Into Statement But With Missing Columns Being Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

If you have 1 table with columns Type and Amount, then another table that has Type, Amount and 12 other columns that are not in table 1, is there an easier way than writing this below?  Repeating "NULL" 12 time just seems archaic, maybe ?  Or is this the only known solution right now ?

There are similar questions on here but none really address the multiple NULL column issue (from what I see), with the classic error of `"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition." coming up in different posts.  I'm using SQL Server 2017.

```
  INSERT INTO Table2 
  SELECT 
    Type
   ,Amount
   ,--Insert 12 NULLs here
  FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the columns after the name of the table:

```
  INSERT INTO Table2 (Type, Amount)
  SELECT 
    Type
   ,Amount
  FROM Table1
```

All the other columns will get a `NULL` or their `DEFAULT` values.
This will not work if the other not specified columns are defined as `NOT NULL` without a `DEFAULT` value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can identify the columns explicitly:

```sql
     INSERT INTO Table2 (Type, Amount)
     SELECT Type, Amount   
     FROM Table1
```

I would think you would need a `WHERE` clause, but this should get you the idea.